# How to check out the current revision of git submodule on Azure Devops?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

My project consists of a hierarchy of git submodules (all hosted on Azure Devops) as follows:

```
A
|- B
   |- C
   |- D
   |- E
```

When creating a YAML pipeline for building on Azure Devops, this entire pipeline can be checked out recursively and each submodule is checked out at the revision specified by its respective parent.  As you would expect.

The depth and complexity of my submodule tree is considerable (far more so than the above diagram) and I would like to improve the performance of some pipelines by only checking out the submodules needed for any particular pipeline.  For example, I might like to only fetch `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

However, when I checkout submodules by hand, they checkout the default branch instead of the revision specified in the parent module.

I understand I can change the branch checked out with the `ref` parameter of the `repository` section with `ref:<branch_name>`, for example.  But that's not exactly what I want.

In the above example, I want to check out the revision of `B` that is referenced by `A`.  And similarly, I want to check out the revisions of `C` and `D` that are referenced by `B` after I have fetched it.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref) for the `ref` property doesn't specify how this is done, if it's even possible, hence my question.

So, how can I do this?  Is there a special ref I can use for the current revision?  Or is this simply not possible with the `ref` property and I need to do this by hand in a script?  (And if the latter, will having a shallow fetch-depth affect this?)

Answer (score 0):

The '**`ref`**' key on the repositories resource can only specify to a particular branch ref (**`refs/heads/<branch name>`**) or a tag ref (**`refs/tags/<tag name>`**). It cannot specify to a particular commit ref.

---

If you want a YAML pipeline run can check out a particular commit ref from the specified repository, you can try like as below:

- Set the repository as a repository resource in the YAML pipeline.
- Manually trigger the YAML pipeline. When manually triggering, you can select which commit ref will be checked out from the repository resource.

**Note:** This method only available when you trigger a pipeline run via manual or REST API ([**Runs - Run Pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)) that allows you to select the commit ref before triggering a run.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

If you really want the feature that the '**`ref`**' key can specify to a particular commit ref, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

---

Comment: Yeah, that's not a viable alternative for me.  These pipelines are meant to be run for pull requests and post-merge builds.  I suspected `ref` couldn't be used in this manner (which is a shame), so for now I've just stuck with checking out the entire hierarchy.  Which takes four minutes instead of ~40 seconds.

Comment: @James, You can try to report a feature request to ask the '**`ref`**' key can support more ref types. I have updated my above answer with the link to report feature requests on Developer Community.

Comment: Yep, I've created a feature request now: 
 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-ref-to-reference-specific-revisi/10541122

Comment: @James, Have helped to vote up your feature request.

Comment: @James, And if the suggestions in my above answer are also helpful for you, maybe, you can accept it.